# same height flex items with scroll bar - flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

how do i create the same height flexbox items and when more text is added to one a scroll bar will appear?

[image: what i want]

```
    .row-1,.row-2{
        display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/o-sewell/pen/PmryKy?editors=1100

Comment: For this to work, you need to set a max height, as it can't be content based ... i.e. like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvXojy

Comment: Do you know which one will have more/less content? I assumed so, and gave a solution below. But if not, let me know and I'll delete the answer if it isn't useful.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelCoker, the css absolute fixed it i think :-)

Comment: awesome you're welcome.

Comment: If the dupe link with the absolute position trick doesn't do it, you need a max-height, and if, let me know

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your CSS along with a set `height` on your div.

```css
.container {
 
}
.row-1,.row-2{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.card {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em;
  height:230px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-1">
    <div class="card card1">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt felis vel enim facilisis, sit amet ornare metus vestibulum. In sollicitudin ipsum et pharetra cursus. Integer iaculis nec enim ut scelerisque. Suspendisse vulputate urna at ipsum blandit aliquam. Morbi mollis sed leo sit amet ultrices. Integer metus purus, blandit convallis sodales ac, mollis sit amet velit. Vestibulum quis massa hendrerit, vulputate arcu vitae, volutpat lorem. Duis nisi magna, ullamcorper sit amet bibendum ut, congue vitae leo. Aenean ultrices tincidunt nisi, at condimentum nulla dignissim iaculis. Praesent ut dui quam. Maecenas eget efficitur quam. Vestibulum hendrerit sem ac ornare ornare. Proin auctor odio mauris, sit amet auctor urna hendrerit sit amet. Proin turpis diam, accumsan ac tempor ac, fringilla a mi. Aliquam quis rhoncus felis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card card2">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt felis vel enim facilisis, sit amet ornare metus vestibulum. In sollicitudin ipsum et pharetra cursus. Integer iaculis nec enim ut scelerisque. Suspendisse vulputate urna at ipsum blandit aliquam. Morbi mollis sed leo sit amet ultrices. Integer metus purus, blandit convallis sodales ac, mollis sit amet velit. Vestibulum quis massa hendrerit, vulputate arcu vitae, volutpat lorem. Duis nisi magna, ullamcorper sit amet bibendum ut, congue vitae leo. Aenean ultrices tincidunt nisi, at condimentum nulla dignissim iaculis. Praesent ut dui quam. Maecenas eget efficitur quam. Vestibulum hendrerit sem ac ornare ornare. Proin auctor odio mauris, sit amet auctor urna hendrerit sit amet. Proin turpis diam, accumsan ac tempor ac, fringilla a mi. Aliquam quis rhoncus felis.</p>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt felis vel enim facilisis, sit amet ornare metus vestibulum. In sollicitudin ipsum et pharetra cursus. Integer iaculis nec enim ut scelerisque. Suspendisse vulputate urna at ipsum blandit aliquam. Morbi mollis sed leo sit amet ultrices. Integer metus purus, blandit convallis sodales ac, mollis sit amet velit. Vestibulum quis massa hendrerit, vulputate arcu vitae, volutpat lorem. Duis nisi magna, ullamcorper sit amet bibendum ut, congue vitae leo. Aenean ultrices tincidunt nisi, at condimentum nulla dignissim iaculis. Praesent ut dui quam. Maecenas eget efficitur quam. Vestibulum hendrerit sem ac ornare ornare. Proin auctor odio mauris, sit amet auctor urna hendrerit sit amet. Proin turpis diam, accumsan ac tempor ac, fringilla a mi. Aliquam quis rhoncus felis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes how does this work with flexbox to make the second card the same height as the first with a scrollbar? do you have any examples

Comment: @Thomas Ray, Where would he have to add it? Or submit a working example.

Comment: There you go: https://codepen.io/Tomraydev/pen/rmEPEy?editors=1100